# jquery making correct callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to correctly make callback in jquery plugin.

```
(function($) {

    var parameter = {
        first:'1',
        second:'2',
        call: $.noop
    };

    var something = 'yes';

    var testf = function(){

        // i neeed launch callback here;

        var something_else = something + 'no';

        alert(something_else)

    }

    $.fn.sadstory = function(options) {

        if (options && typeof options === 'object') 
        {
            $.extend(parameter, options);
        }

        testf();

        return this;

    }

})(jQuery);
```

and i need atccess var and owerwrite or making somthing else with him.

```
$('elm').sadstory({
 call: function(){
  this.something = 'no';
 }
});
```

and result would by alert box with text nono instead of yesno, now to make this callback correctly.

Comment: A note: `parameter` is a shared object in your plugin and calling `$.extend(parameter, options)`  most likely will result in an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it like that:

```
$.fn.sadstory = function(options,callback) {

    if (options && typeof options === 'object') 
    {
        $.extend(parameter, options);
    }

    testf();

    // example, var c is passed to callback function
    var c= "abc";
    callback(c);

    return this;

}
```

you can call like

```
.sadstory({..},function(c) {
 console.log(c) // logs "abc"
})
```

should also work as property of options

Answer (score 0):

`this.something` doesn't exist. The only `something` is a variable with the scope of your `testf` method.

A solution is to pass an object as a parameter to the callback, and allow the callback to modify this object.

```
(function($) {

    var parameter = {
        first:'1',
        second:'2',
        call: $.noop
    };

    var something = 'yes';

    var testf = function(){

        // Initialize the string to a default value
        var stringGenerationParams = { something: 'yes' };

        // Allow the callback to modify the string generation params
        parameter.call(stringGenerationParams);

        // At this point, stringGenerationParams.something may have been 
        // modified by the callback function
        var something_else = stringGenerationParams.something + 'no';

        alert(something_else)

    }

    $.fn.sadstory = function(options) {

        if (options && typeof options === 'object') 
        {
            $.extend(parameter, options);
        }

        testf();

        return this;

    }

})(jQuery);
```

And now, this will work:

```
$('elm').sadstory({
       call: function(e) {
           e.something = 'no';
       }
   });
```

Comment: and how about atccess global function($) from call ?

Comment: @fees: sorry, I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: call: function(e) {
 somefunction();
}

somefunction() function from plugin